# How do I view syntax-highlighted source code for operators e.g. %in%?

Tags: r, rstudio

In RStudio, I know that if I press F2 while the caret is on a function name I will be shown the source code for that function as if it was an open R script, which syntax highlighting and everything.

How do I do the same for operators like `%in%` and names like `if`? These things don't work:

1. Typing `%in%` into the script or console and pressing F2/Go To Definition.
2. Typing `%in%` (surrounded by backticks) into the script or console and pressing F2/Go To Definition.

The only way I can view their source code is by running `%in%` in the console, where it shows me an unhighlighted version.

Thanks!

Comment: try `View(`%in%`)` - with backticks aroun the %in%

Comment: @RAB looks like a good answer

Comment: sweet, added as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see them by using `View()` with backticks around the argument:

```
View(`%in%`)
View(`if`)
```